# Parsing Challenges of HTML in Rich Text

Tags: richtext-editor

We occasionally have to programmatically elide text retrieved from Sitecore to fit correctly on certain pages.  Sometimes this is rich text, containing html markup which breaks when the elision removes closing tags beyond the truncation point.

It's probably preferable to add arbitrary closing tags at the end of the elided text, but it may also be permissible to convert the html to plain text in the context where we do this.  I'm not sure how to do either.  Does anyone have advice on the best way to go about this?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976457/157833 ?

Comment: Can you tell your logics while eliding the text? If it is something like maxlength, then you can probably set it as a validation on your field in Sitecore. Omitting characters programmatically works but it can cause uncertain consequences. You should probably have correct validations in place and train authors correctly to prevent this.

Comment: I can't use a Sitecore validation because the requirement varies with context.  At some places in the site it needs to be elided to a specific length, in others the same context gets displayed in its entirety.

Comment: Still assessing the HtmlAgilityPack solution.  It looks promising, but some temporary issues with my local development environment are keeping me from checking it out thoroughly at the moment....

Comment: Update:  the HtmlAgilityPack solution eventually worked out.  I had to add some code to it to clean up some tags that wound up being blank after their text was deleted, but it eventually worked.